# T-SQL to modify a field in any database where it exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have about 150 SQL Server 2005 databases all mostly copies of each other. Each one has a table called bvc_User that has a field called PasswordChanged. For now, PasswordChanged is a nullable bit field.

I want to change all instances of it to a non-nullable bit field with a default value of 0 and set any NULL values currently in the table data to 1 (yes, I don't want them set to the default of 0).

I can probably do the update of the NULL setting and the corresponding update of the already existing database values separately, but my primary question is, how can I loop through all the databases on a server, look for the bvc_User table (not all DB's on the server have it) and if it exists, alter the PasswordChanged field?

Comment: What do you mean by "a single T-SQL command"? Do you mean a single line of executable T-SQL?

Comment: Question/tags updated to reflect SQL Server 2005. Also, by "single t-sql" command, it doesn't need to be a single statement. Just something I can drop into a New Query window and run once.

Comment: Also edited to clarify the question a little bit and removed the "single command" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use sp_msforeachdb to run a command on all database.  Notice that I check for the existence of the table prior to actually using it.

```
sp_msforeachdb '
  If Exists(Select 1 
            From   [?].Information_Schema.Tables 
            Where  Table_Name = ''bvc_User'')
    Update [?].dbo.bvc_User 
    Set    PasswordChanged = 1 
    Where  PasswordChanged Is NULL'
```

Comment: +1 - Beat me to it.  Same method works for `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN` command.

Comment: Thanks. I figured I'd be able to apply the same process to both the ALTER TABLE and the UPDATE command.

Answer (score 0):

Three pieces: get the db names, loop through them, execute dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @dbNames TABLE (Id int IDENTITY, name nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO @dbNames
SELECT name FROM sysdatabases

DECLARE @statement nvarchar(540)
DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(50)

DECLARE @maxId int

SELECT @maxId = MAX(Id) FROM @dbNames

DECLARE @i int

SET @i = 1

WHILE @i < @maxId
BEGIN
SEt @dbName = 'dbName'

SET @statement = 'USE ' + @dbName + CHAR(13) + '--execute table specific alter table logic here'

EXEC sp_ExecuteSql @statement
SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

HTH.